# Pyqt5 combobox allow search but prevent add

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qcombobox

how can i make `QComboBox` allow search but preventing user from adding new item
my code :

```
self.products = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.conts[self.ind])
self.products.setEditable(True)
self.products.resize(190, 30)
self.products.move(400, 20)
self.products.setStyleSheet('background:#2c3e50')
self.products.show()
```

`self.products.setEditable(True)` is not what i need because user can type any thing

How to prevent user from adding new item , just search for currently setted items

Answer (score 2):

As you point out you have to enable the [`editable`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#editable-prop) property and set the [`insertPolicy`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#insertPolicy-prop) property to [`QComboBox::NoInsert`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#InsertPolicy-enum):

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
    w.setEditable(True)
    w.setInsertPolicy(QtWidgets.QComboBox.NoInsert)
    w.addItems(["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"])
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```